# RailsAdmin and Devise - displaying username in tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [rails_admin gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) and Devise in my app where I have a Post model.

Each Post belongs to a User. Users have a `:username` attribute

I'm trying to configure rails_admin to display the user's username in the list view but instead it's displaying "User #1", "User #2" etc

Here's my rails_admin code:

```
config.model Post do 
  label "Blog"    
  list do
    field :id
    field :title
    field :published
    field :user_id
    field :created_at
  end
end
```

I'd really like rails_admin to display the :username for each user. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `object_label`:

```
config.model Post do 
  label "Blog"    
  object_label do
    "#{bindings[:object].user.username}"
  end
  list do
    field :id
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've spent hours on this today :)